# Sharepoint 2013 custom lists as inventory system

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have this custom list that acts as an inventory database(lookup column)[image]

I have this custom list to create requests of items from the image above

[image]

The inventory database should automatically update whenever a request is filed. For example, After filing for 10 A4 Bond Paper, it should automatically change the quantity of my inventory database to 4990.

How can I make this happen?

**EDIT**

I've come up with this workflow[image: workflow] but I thinks it wouldn't be a good practice since for example I have 500 items in my inventory, that would let me do 500 if-else's and everytime I will add new item, I will have to edit my workflow.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You have this correctly, created two lists where you have one with Total Amount and second with Requests.

On Requests list create simply **SharePoint workflow**, where you will find item in List Inventory by filter **Name = CurrentItem:Item1** (LookUpField) and after this do calculation **Quantity = Quantity-1**

Comment: thank you for your response, see edit for clarifications